# Compare specific field from two different database table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, vb.net, synchronization

I'm actually developing a synchronization tool in `vb.net`, I have two database that have on each table records field `GUID`, this field help to have the same PK on both database. On each record there is also a field called `lastUpdated`, this field have a milliseconds value, so prevent two user to update the record in the same time. My question is, how I can compare the records of the same table from different db? For example:

**ONLINE_DATABASE**

*TABLE_1*

```
| ID |   GUID                             | NAME  |    LASTUPDATED              |
| 5  | 054ba092-b476-47ed-810b-32868cc95fb| John  | 06-01-2016 17:01:12.472438  |
```

**CLIENT_DATABASE**

*TABLE_1*

```
| ID |   GUID                             | NAME  |    LASTUPDATED              |
| 9  | 054ba092-b476-47ed-810b-32868cc95fb| Jack  | 06-01-2016 18:01:12.472438  |
```

How you can see I've update the record from client application, so I need to apply the same change to online database. Now I've a thousand records to check in about ten tables. So my question is, how I can made a system that do this? Actually I tough to read each row with a `MySqlCommand reader` but I also think that this procedure is slow... Suggest?

NOTICE THAT: the table have the same name in both db

Comment: are you looking for (psuedo) `if o.tbl1.LastUpdate > c.tbl1.LastUpdated Then .... copy o to c ELSE ... copu c to o `?

Comment: Well to be honest, my problem is to compare the data read from the local db to the online db. For now I just want to update the data of the online app, so any changes that will be made online will not be considered by the client application. I should create a method that reads data client (with the connection string for db client), then create a method that receives as a parameter the MyCommand, read the data from online db with the record passed and return the lastUpdated field. My idea is if lastUpdated (online) is less than the client, then I upgrade if  missing, I insert.. No idea anyway.

Comment: Anyway, yes, your pseudo is more or less correct, 'cause there are some case to take into account. If the record missing in the db online, or missing in the local db.. But yes this is the way.

Comment: You might start by saving the time of the last time you processed it...or the oldest datetime encountered.  Then load a datatable with "SELECT ... WHERE LastUpDated > varLastTime"  that gives you the new stuff in the (local?) db...maybe subtract a day to be certain.  It seems like ALL of those need to be processed in one way or another (depending on the integrity of the timestamp)

Comment: Have you thought about MySql´s built-in [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication.html) mechanism?

Comment: How exactly MySql replication should working in vb.net? There is some example class? I need to update the data not reply.

Comment: [How to Set Up Replication - MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-howto.html)  then there is always [this](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+C%23+VB+mysql+replication)

Comment: @Plutonix MySql documentation doesn't spoke about vb.net, I need a code example. Anyway, I think that a better solution would be compare the records table each